# concating two columns next to eachother

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I've written a function that collects some data via input(), its unimportant to the question at hand. However at the end I need to .concat two columns.
So far I've got it working to an extent but its not perfect.
{def visualise_country():

```
data = pd.read_csv('tas_pr_1991_2015_AC.csv')

target_frame = get_info()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data['country'] == target_frame[0]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[df1['year'] == int(target_frame[2])])
df1 = df1[target_frame[4]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data['country'] == target_frame[1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.loc[df2['year'] == int(target_frame[3])])
df2 = df2[target_frame[4]]

frame_list = [df1,df2]

df = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=1)

print("Data for {} in comparison with {}. Comparison years for {}: {} and {}: ".format(target_frame[0],target_frame[1],target_frame[0],target_frame[2],target_frame[1],target_frame[3]))

return df}
```

Target_frame is just a tuple containing the collected information necessary to collect the columns.

Output:

```
1 - NaN 
2 - NaN 
3 - NaN
4 - NaN
NaN - 5
NaN - 6
NaN - 7
NaN - 8
```

Desired output:

```
1 - 5
2 - 6
3 - 7
4 - 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need same index values in all `DataFrames`:

```
frame_list = [x.reset_index(drop=True) for x in [df1,df2]]
```

Or:

```
df1.index = df2.index
frame_list = [df1,df2]
df = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1[target_frame[4]].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2[target_frame[4]].reset_index(drop=True)
frame_list = [df1,df2]
df = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df_1,df_2],axis=1)` works without re_indexing

Comment: @pyd - For OP not,  because got `NaN`s.

Comment: Ya I'm getting his desired output without resetting @jezrael

Comment: @pyd - What are your input data? OP dont get them.

Comment: Yes, I checked with the sample data given in the question [1234],[5678]